# String cannot be converted to double error in a function

Tags: java, double

I am trying to output NaN in string format when x is NaN. However, the console throws up String cannot be converted to double error when I am trying to return string of "NaN" when Double.isNaN is true. I tried parsing string r as a double using Double.parseDouble() but to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
public static double heaviside(double x) {
    String r = "NaN";
    r = Double.parseDouble(r);
    double result;
    if (Double.isNaN(x)) return r;
    else if (x < 0.0) return result = 0.0;
    else if (x == 0.0) return result = 0.5;
    else return result = 1.0;
}
```

Console output

> ActivationFunction.java:6: error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to String
>           r = Double.parseDouble(r);
>                                 ^
>       ActivationFunction.java:8: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double
>           if (Double.isNaN(x)) return r;
>                                       ^

Comment: And if `x` is NaN, why don't you just return `x`?

Comment: I suggest you using an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse. They are very helpful when learning a new language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert String into double and storing its value in `r` which is a type of `String`.

You should create another variable of `double` type and can store that value in that like this:

```
public static double heaviside(double x) {
    String r = "NaN";
    double d = Double.parseDouble(r);
    double result;
    if (Double.isNaN(x)) return d;
    else if (x < 0.0) return result = 0.0;
    else if (x == 0.0) return result = 0.5;
    else return result = 1.0;
}
```

I hope it will help you. 
Happy coding..!

Comment: The question is, what is the point of all of this? "If x is NaN, create a new double representing NaN and return that new value". Why don't just return `x` in the first place?

Comment: You are right. I give this much explanation because @palerabbit can understand that he was trying to store double into String and that is an actual error that he mentioned into question.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was trying to get "NaN" in my output instead of infinity but yes what you have here makes alot of sense! cheers @Amongalen

Answer (score 3):

You problem comes from the fact, that you try to assign `double` to `String` variable. `r` is defines as `String` `and Double.parseDouble(r)` returns `double`. It will work if you assing it to `result` instead, like so: `double result = Double.parseDouble(r);`

However, there is no need to parse new `double` from `String` in the first place. You want to return `NaN` when `x == NaN`. You can just return `x` in that case because, well, `x` is `NaN`. No need for another variable, parsing and all of that.

Answer (score 0):

"NaN" is not a double, you can't convert it to double and not return `x` because Java returns an exception on line 2 of your code and does not continue to run the rest of the code

Comment: Funny enough, I've just tried `double test = Double.parseDouble("NaN");` and... it runs just fine.

Comment: The error in that line is not that "NaN" is not a double. But that parseDouble returns a double and not a String, so you cannot assign it to a String.

Comment: I agree with you @Amongalen, I run that too and it works fine not sure why. 
But I think, I tried to print in 1System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("NaN))` which converts double into String again.

Comment: Compilation errors are not exceptions, and neither compilation errors nor exceptions are returned. Don't misuse standard terminology.